# Page level scrolling per TabBarView with widgets on top

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I would like to implement the following behavior in Flutter for web where scrollbars allow to scroll all the way up and down of the page on any of the tabs. Scrolling on the ListView should take us to the top of the page and not only to the top of the list.

[image]

### Code

```dart
class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return [
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Sliver 1')),
                ),
              ),
              const SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Center(
                child: TabBar(
                  labelColor: Colors.black,
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(text: 'Sliver Tab 1'),
                    Tab(text: 'Sliver Tab 2'),
                  ],
                ),
              )),
            ];
          },
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              ListView.builder(
                  // controller: ScrollController(),
                  itemCount: 1000,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                        height: 50,
                        color: index.isEven ? Colors.red : Colors.white,
                        child: AliveKeeper(index: index),
                      )),
              ListView.builder(
                // controller: ScrollController(),
                itemCount: 1000,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: index.isEven ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
                  child: AliveKeeper(index: index),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AliveKeeper extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;

  const AliveKeeper({
    required this.index,
    GlobalKey? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  AliveKeeperState createState() => AliveKeeperState();
}

class AliveKeeperState extends State<AliveKeeper>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Text('Item ${widget.index}');
  }
}
```

As you can see [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/101320), I've tried different implementations using NestedScrollView but I haven't got the expected behavior.

Keep in mind that each TarBarView must be configured with keep alive.

Thanks.

Comment: Add grid view.., on hover mouse... Please show some code...

Comment: @GOKU The code can be found in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/101320

Comment: Hello, ListView.builder replace to GridView.builder  and Container wrap to hover

Answer (score 0):

Try this code I think helps this

and mouse hovers example :

> https://protocoderspoint.com/hover-effect-with-animation-flutter-web/

this code only GridView example

```
class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return [
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Sliver 1')),
                ),
              ),
              const SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Center(
                child: TabBar(
                  labelColor: Colors.black,
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(text: 'Sliver Tab 1'),
                    Tab(text: 'Sliver Tab 2'),
                  ],
                ),
              )),
            ];
          },
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              GridView.builder(
 gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                crossAxisCount: 3,  
                  crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,  
                  mainAxisSpacing: 4.0  

),
                  
                  itemCount: 1000,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                        height: 50,
                        color: index.isEven ? Colors.red : Colors.white,
                        child: AliveKeeper(index: index),
                      )),
              GridView.builder(
 gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
               crossAxisCount: 3,  
                  crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,  
                  mainAxisSpacing: 4.0  

),
                  
                  itemCount: 1000,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                        height: 50,
                        color: index.isEven ? Colors.red : Colors.white,
                        child: AliveKeeper(index: index),
                      )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AliveKeeper extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;

  const AliveKeeper({
    required this.index,
    GlobalKey? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  AliveKeeperState createState() => AliveKeeperState();
}

class AliveKeeperState extends State<AliveKeeper>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Text('Item ${widget.index}');
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, the expected behavior is referring to the scroll bars changing tabs and not to on hover effects.

Answer (score 0):

`TabBarView` uses `PageView` and it uses children max height for `TabBarView`'s children.  While your goal is to keep alive, you can use `SingleChildScrollView`, this answer main goal is to control the scroll-bar as per tab.

Run on [dartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=32cbd0d0e340afb936010a2f69a2b588).

```dart
class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final int tabLength = 3;
  late final controller = TabController(length: tabLength, vsync: this)
    ..addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.black12,
                child: const Center(child: Text('Sliver 1')),
              ),
              TabBar(
                controller: controller,
                labelColor: Colors.black,
                tabs: List.generate(
                  tabLength,
                  (i) => Tab(text: 'Sliver Tab ${i + 1}'),
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                onHorizontalDragEnd: (details) {
                  if (details.primaryVelocity == null) return;
                  debugPrint(details.primaryVelocity.toString());

                  if (details.primaryVelocity! > 0) {
                    debugPrint("move Left");
                    controller.animateTo(
                        controller.index < 0 ? 0 : controller.index - 1);
                  } else if (details.primaryVelocity! < 0) {
                    debugPrint("move right");
                    controller.animateTo(controller.index >= tabLength
                        ? tabLength - 1
                        : controller.index + 1);
                  }
                },
                child:

                    /// or any animation builder you prefer
                    AnimatedSwitcher(
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                  transitionBuilder: (child, animation) {
                    return ScaleTransition(
                      scale: animation,
                      child: child,
                    );
                  },
                  child: [
                    tab1(),
                    tab2(),
                    tab3(),
                  ].elementAt(controller.index),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Column tab2() {
    return Column(
      children: List.generate(
        22,
        (index) => Container(
          height: 50,
          width: double.infinity,
          color: index.isEven ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
          child: AliveKeeper(index: index),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Column tab3() {
    return Column(
      children: List.generate(
        22,
        (index) => Container(
          height: 50,
          width: double.infinity,
          color: index.isEven ? Colors.pink : Colors.white,
          child: AliveKeeper(index: index),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Column tab1() {
    return Column(
      children: List.generate(
          32,
          (index) => Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 50,
                color: index.isEven ? Colors.red : Colors.white,
                child: AliveKeeper(index: index),
              )),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Some additional question before I accept it as the answer.
1) This solution works only for two tabs. Can you modify it to support N tabs?
2) Could you also add support for lazy loading of the widgets that are not selected initially?

Thanks.

Comment: we can use `onHorizontalDragEnd` in that case, I am using `AnimatedSwitcher` with `ScaleTransition`, you can use `AnimatedBuilder` for more customization,

Comment: Can you please modify the code accordingly with the lazy loading change?

Comment: @Nagual included on test case.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView.builder(
  primary = false;
  ......
  ......

),
```

Might help you with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

here I have tried to solve using CustomScrollController.

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

import 'demo/navigation.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Custom Clipper',
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        // add tabBarTheme
        tabBarTheme: TabBarTheme(
            labelColor: Colors.pink[800],
            labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.pink[800]), // color for text
            indicator: const UnderlineTabIndicator(
                // color for indicator (underline)
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black12))),
        primaryColor: Colors.pink[800], // outdated and has no effect to Tabbar
        // deprecated,
      ),
      // initialRoute: NavigationUtils.routeHome,
      // onGenerateRoute: NavigationUtils.generateRoute,
      home: const UsersList(),
    );
  }
}

class UsersList extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? searchString;

  const UsersList({Key? key, this.searchString}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UsersListState createState() => _UsersListState();
}

class _UsersListState extends State<UsersList>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  //for display search bar
  bool isShowSearchBar = false;

  //creating dynamic a list for side popup menu
  List<PopupMenuItem> popUpMenuItem = [];

  //Scroll controller
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  //TabBar controller
  late TabController tbController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    //initializing with 4 tab items
    tbController = TabController(length: 4, vsync: this);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
      controller: _scrollController,

      scrollBehavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
      physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
      slivers: [
        SliverAppBar(
          title: searchBar(),
          backgroundColor: isShowSearchBar ? Colors.white : null,
          elevation: 0,
          pinned: true,
          floating: true,
        ),
        SliverAppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 200,
          title: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
            child: Row(children: [
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 90,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                height: 200,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
                child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: const [
                      Text(
                        "Name: Rohit Chaurasiya",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      Text("posts: 13", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                    ]),
              ))
            ]),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          elevation: 0,
          bottom: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize:
                Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, kToolbarHeight),
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              children: [
                const Divider(
                  thickness: 1,
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  height: 15,
                ),
                TabBar(
                    controller: tbController,
                    isScrollable: true,
                    indicatorColor: Colors.black,
                    indicatorWeight: 5,
                    indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                    indicator: const UnderlineTabIndicator(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 3.0),
                        insets: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 45)),
                    tabs: const [
                      Icon(Icons.camera_alt_outlined),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                        child: Tab(
                          text: "CHATS",
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                        child: Tab(text: "STATUS"),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                        child: Tab(text: "CALLS"),
                      )
                    ]),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SliverFillRemaining(
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: tbController,
            children: [
              ListView.builder(
                physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: 100,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Text("Camera $index");
                },
              ),
              ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 100,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Text("Chat $index");
                },
              ),
              const Center(
                child: Text("STATUS"),
              ),
              const Center(
                child: Text("CALLS"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
      shrinkWrap: true,
    ));
  }

  Widget searchBar() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        (isShowSearchBar)
            ? Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Search...",
                      prefixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.search,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      )),
                  onChanged: (searchQuery) {
                    setState(() {
                      searchQuery = searchQuery.toLowerCase();
                    });
                  },
                ),
              )
            : const Text("MyChat"),
        Row(
          children: [
            InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    isShowSearchBar = !isShowSearchBar;
                  });
                },
                child: Icon(
                  isShowSearchBar ? Icons.close : Icons.search,
                  color: isShowSearchBar ? Colors.grey : Colors.white,
                )),
            PopupMenuButton(
                icon: const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.ellipsisV),
                onSelected: _selectedMenu,
                itemBuilder: (context) => popUpMenuItem)
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  void _selectedMenu(value) {
    log("Selected menu => " + value.toString());
  }
}

class UserListTileWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const UserListTileWidget({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () async {
        try {} on PlatformException catch (e) {
          log("sdfcsfg");
        }
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 20,
          vertical: 15,
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                    spreadRadius: 2,
                    blurRadius: 5,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: const CircleAvatar(
                radius: 25,
                backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/images/contact.jpeg"),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.65,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 20,
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        children: const <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            "Rohit",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          /*Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                            width: 7,
                            height: 7,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              color: Colors.orange,
                            ),
                          )*/
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
  // Override behavior methods and getters like dragDevices
  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
        PointerDeviceKind.touch,
        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
        // etc.
      };
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, use ListView.builder as children of TabBarView and you will realize the behaviour of your solution is not as expected.

Comment: ok, let you know after checking

Comment: Do you mean bouncing issue or any other?

Comment: I have updated the code you can check again.

Comment: Please, pay attention to the expected scrolling behaviour from the video of the question. Scrolling on the ListView should take us to the top of the page and not only to the top of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple `ScrollController`s for various scrollable `Widget`s that you have, and coordinate/synchronize their `ScrollPosition`s by listening to changes in their `ScrollController`s.

Checkout this [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=ce0bc83639c4cbbf9e93109108efe055). I have added a third tab in DartPad which changes the size dynamically.

```dart
static void controllerListener(
    ScrollController parent,
    ScrollController child,
    ScrollController sc,
    bool movedScrollbar,
  ) {
    final childPX = child.position.pixels;
    final parentPX = parent.position.pixels;
    final parentPXMax = parent.position.maxScrollExtent;

    if (childPX >= 0 && parentPX < parentPXMax) {
      parent.position.moveTo(childPX + parentPX);
    } else {
      final currenParentPos = childPX + parentPX;
      parent.position.moveTo(currenParentPos);
    }

    if (!movedScrollbar) {
      sc.position.moveTo(parentPX + childPX);
    }
  }

  @override
```

this function scrolls header widgets according to changes in `ListView` widget.

Also you wanted a page level Scrollbar, therefore I made a `SingleChildScrollView` spanning the whole page and according `Scrollbar` position changes in `SingleChildScrollView` widget I changed the main `Widget`. If you think the calculation for scroll position is off you can change the `scrollController.addListener` code starting from line `199` in DartPad.

[image]